# Prove the following statements: Linear algebra (Vector spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let $V$ be a vector space and $P \subseteq V$ a subset. Proof that the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $P$ is linearly independent. 
(ii) Each vector in $ \operatorname{vect}(P)$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $P$.

Hint: Use contradiction for (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) by presuming that a vector can be expressed as two linear combinations of vectors from $P$.

So let's assume a vector $x = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\a_2 \\a_3 \\\end{bmatrix}$ can be expressed by two linear combinations from vectors out of $P$. 
This implies that there isn't a unique way to express a vector with two linear combinations from vectors from $P$. 
This contradicts (ii). I don't really know what is required for a sufficient proof. Corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show that the negation of (ii) contradicts (i), not (ii) (which it trivially does)

Comment: Well yeah, just like in the example on this wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

Comment: But how do you that here? Is one allowed to say it is trivial and just move on. Because the best thing I can think of is just write a particular vector like my $x$ and say it can be written in two other vectors of $P$.

Comment: You have to show that if a vector is a linear combination of the elements in $P$ in two distinct ways, then $P$ is not linearly independent. This is by no means trivial and requires proof.

Comment: You're almost there.  Try and contradict (i).  It's not trivial.  Use the definition of linear independence too.

Comment: So if I use the following definition $a_1\vec x_1 +a_2\vec x_2 + a_3\vec x_3 + \ldots + a_k\vec x_k=0 $ to write two vectors $\vec x_1 = - \frac {a_3}{a_1}\vec x_3 + \ldots + \frac {a_k}{a_1} \vec x_k$ and $\vec x_2 = - \frac {a_3}{a_2}\vec x_3 + \ldots + \frac {a_k}{a_2} \vec x_k$ would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(i)\implies (ii)$ we have

$$a_1\vec v_1+\ldots+a_n\vec v_n=b_1\vec v_1+\ldots+b_n\vec v_n \implies (a_1-b_1)\vec v_1+\ldots+(a_n-b_n)\vec v_n=0 \\\implies a_1=b_1,\ldots,a_n=b_n$$

For $(ii)\implies (i)$ suppose  $P$ is not linearly independent, then exists

$$c_1\vec v_1+\ldots+c_n\vec v_n=\vec 0$$

for some $c_i$ not all equal to zero. Therefore for any $w\in \operatorname{vect}(P)
$ we have

$$\vec w=a_1\vec v_1+\ldots+a_n\vec v_n$$

and

$$\vec w=\vec w+\vec 0=(a_1+c_1)\vec v_1+\ldots+(a_n+c_n)\vec v_n$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: Please correct my last comment.

Comment: Oh, ok I see now. I'm not used to construct good logical proofs only induction type ones.

Comment: @AnonymousI Thanks for the edit, I add the vector symbol also to the zero vector!

Answer (score 2):

$\lnot$(i)$\implies\lnot$(ii): If $P$ is linearly dependent, $0$ can be expressed in multiple ways as a linear combination of elements of $P$.

$\lnot$(ii)$\implies\lnot$(i): If a vector $v$ can be expressed by two different linear combinations of elements of $P$, *subtract these* to arrive a nontrivial linear combination resulting in $0$.

Comment: Just like a contraposition in the wikipedia articles I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not stipulated the vector space is $K^3$ ($K$ being the base field), nor that it has finite dimension.

Second, the proof is not really by contradiction, but by *contrapositive*. 
The hint suggests to assumesome vector  $v$ can be written as two *different* linear combinations with finite support of the vectors in $P$:
$$v=\sum_{u\in P}\lambda_u u=\sum_{u\in P}\mu_u u, \tag{1}$$
and to deduce the set of vectors $P$ is not linearly independent. But that is obvious, since you can rewrite eq. $(1)$ as
$$\sum_{u\in P}(\lambda_u-\mu_u) u= 0$$
which is a non-trivial linear relation between the elements of $P$ since not all coefficients $\lambda_u, \mu_u$ are equal.

Comment: Cf. my reference link in the comments.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to insist on the difference with proofs by contradiction.  Quite often, so-called ‘proofs by contradiction’ are really proofs by contrapositive.